# Data frame loses formatting on using sub()

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame which looks a bit like this:

```
   ID          Hero Win Rate Matches Played KDA Ratio Wraith King Abaddon   Lich  Lycan Centaur Warrunner   Zeus Necrophos Death Prophet
27          Slardar   52.32%      2,741,067      2.42      -0.63%  -2.16% -3.01%  2.40%            -0.75% -3.29%    -1.93%        -1.83%
50             Doom   49.10%      3,202,905      2.50      -3.57%   1.72% -0.74% -3.12%             0.03% -1.76%    -0.88%        -2.62%
78    Bounty Hunter   45.29%      4,146,758      2.17      -1.56%  -2.67% -1.43%  0.51%            -2.17% -3.33%    -2.19%         0.63%
92             Chen   44.34%        546,677      1.72      -0.27%  -0.51% -1.35% -0.81%            -0.24% -0.33%     0.03%        -1.33%
```

I seem to be able to assign e.g. the 1st row to a new data.frame by doing this:

```
newdataframe <- data.frame(Hero=subsetheroes[1,2],subsetheroes[1,6:ncol(subsetheroes)],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Where subsetheroes is the old data.frame. It works:

```
Hero Wraith.King Abaddon   Lich Lycan Centaur.Warrunner   Zeus Necrophos Death.Prophet Terrorblade Vengeful.Spirit Omniknight
27 Slardar      -0.63%  -2.16% -3.01% 2.40%            -0.75% -3.29%    -1.93%        -1.83%      -1.35%          -1.65%     -1.79%
```

However, I want to convert the rows with percentages in them to raw numbers, and assign them to a new data frame. I thought this would work:

```
totals <- data.frame(Hero=subsetheroes[1,2],as.numeric(sub("%", "", subsetheroes[1,6:ncol(subsetheroes)])),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Unfortuately, the output of this looks as follows:

```
       Hero as.numeric.sub..........subsetheroes.1..6.ncol.subsetheroes....
1   Slardar                                                           -0.63
2   Slardar                                                           -2.16
3   Slardar                                                           -3.01
4   Slardar                                                            2.40
```

The numbers are beautifully converted, but it is making each entry a new row, and repeating column #1.

Why is this behaving so strangely by adding the as.number() and sub() functions?

EDIT: I've put the code to generate the table here: http://pastebin.com/rRKYxawV - the subsetheroes table is just a few lines from the heroestable using the subset() function.

Comment: I was going to show you a much simpler way to do this, but reading in your example data is a huge pain in the butt, since you only showed the output of `head` and you have goofy column names with spaces in them. So all I can do is suggest that you read the second paragraph of the Value section of `?data.frame` for an explanation for why this isn't strange behavior at all. It's behaving exactly as documented.

Comment: The reason I have strange heading titles is because I'm using readHTMLTable() on http://dotabuff.com/heroes/slardar/matchups - I didn't name the column names... but if there's a way for me to make them single words then I'm happy to...

Comment: Just provide the output of `dput(head(...))` instead.

Comment: Hi Joran, that's a great idea. Indeed, `dput(head(subsetheroes))` works great, but `sub("%", "", dput(head(subsetheroes)))` again it seems to change the formatting completely, even though DPUT just outputs ASCII and I'm sub()ing: `[1] "c(\"\", \"\", \"\", \"\")"                                   "c(\"Slardar\", \"Doom\", \"Bounty Hunter\", \"Chen\")"      
  [3] "c(\"52.32\", \"49.10%\", \"45.29%\", \"44.34%\")"            "c(\"2,741,067\", \"3,202,905\", \"4,146,758\", \"546,677\")"`

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. In order for folks to answer questions effectively, we need example data to work with. Normally, one could copy+paste your example data into `read.table(text = "")` and then work with it, but because of the goofy column names, that doesn't work. Providing the output from `dput` in your questions give people who are trying to help you something that they can easily read into R themselves and work with.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've put the code here: http://pastebin.com/rRKYxawV - subsetheroes is just like heroestable but a few lines selected using the subset() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- subsetheroes[,c(2,6:ncol(subsetheroes))]
x[,2:ncol(x)] <- lapply(x[,2:ncol(x)],function(x) as.numeric(gsub(pattern="%","",x,fixed = TRUE)))
```

That grabs everything, not just one row, but you get the idea. Skip trying to use `data.frame`. Just subset and then do the substitutions and conversions separately.